# How to specify how many pixels scroll moves on each step?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

When I use mouse wheel to scroll content in `div` I want it to scroll by e.g., `30px` each step or each mouse wheel tick w/e is the best solution.
I would prefer `performance > ease` i.e. I'm preferring `javascript > jquery`

Comment: I would recommend letting the user's operating system handle that. It's not usually a good user experience to change how a user's mouse works just because you think it should be done differently.

Comment: When you come up with your own solution it is best to write it as an answer not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I fiddled some solution of my own, you can see example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/mP974/)**
Thanks [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034736/tom) for leading me to this answer.

**JS:**

```
function wheel($div,deltaY){
   var step = 30;
   var pos = $div.scrollTop();
   var nextPos = pos + (step*(-deltaY))
   console.log("DelatY: " + deltaY + ", Step: " + step + ", nextPos: " + nextPos);
   $div.scrollTop(nextPos);
}

$('#test').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    wheel($(this),deltaY);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Used libraries:**

- jQuery 1.8.3
- jQuery mousewheel

Answer (score 6):

There's big problems in implementing mousewheel details yourself, since there is (AFAIK) three different behaviours that the browsers are currently doing. Everything but Firefox currently supports `mousewheel` event, which passes a `wheelDelta` parameter of 120 per "click". Firefox has `DOMMouseScroll` event, that will pass a `detail` parameter of 3 (I think) per "click", and in the opposite direction. Apple devices have a much more granular resolution, and have a deceleration to them; so Webkit browsers give also delta in the two axes, and there are no "clicks" on a trackpad two-fingered scroll. Finally, DOM Level 3 Events draft standard will define a "click" being (I think) 1, and provide a possibility of three axes; so you need to future-proof your code. So implementing your own wheel handler is kind of a pain (I know since I am now implementing zooming for my SVG app using the mousewheel).

You can consult Javascript: The Definitive Guide, chapter 17.6 Mousewheel Events, for more details.