# how to Scroll to the end of a div in a single scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a div with 100% height of the screen and i want it to scroll [like this website](http://kerriscreation.com/en/#graph). One little scroll should take me to the end of a division.

```
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#target-element").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

I was using this code but its not working. Help

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564561/how-to-specify-how-many-pixels-scroll-moves-on-each-step#18564860)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should works:

```
$( "body" ).scroll(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#target-element").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```