# jQuery mouse wheel roll size 'jump'

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I make dynamic scroll content in div. And I would like get in script how many pixels have one scroll 'roll' in mouse/touchpad. I can't take constant value, because in system (Windows) is option to set how many lines 'jump' one rolls. Sometimes is option to set, that one roll scroll, scroll one page, not lines.

Is possible to get any information from system/browser about size jump scrolling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564561/how-to-specify-how-many-pixels-scroll-moves-on-each-step

Comment: After read topic from link, I think that this isn't possible. But thank You for link, because I had realy big problem with ask question for Google :-)

Comment: But... example form link have bug... because in `event.originalEvent.deltaY` is information about one 'jump'...