# Webkit scrolling too much?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have some content which can have only specific height (no more), and I added some scroll on that content.

This is my CSS:

```
.value {
  max-height: 60px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* width */
.value::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
}
/* Track */
.value::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgb(163, 163, 163);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/* Handle */
.value::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, #b95aca, #8c15ad);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

And This is my Subtitle content:

```
<div 
   class="value"  
  *ngIf="courseData.sub_title"
> {{courseData.sub_title}}
</div>
```

This is the image:

[image]

So, when I want to scroll down or up using mouse wheel it's scrolling too much and user can not be able read full text (part of text was going up or down with scrolling).

How can I change scroll step?

Comment: I don't think you can set scroll step in css, you will have to manually implement scroll by wheel like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564561/how-to-specify-how-many-pixels-scroll-moves-on-each-step. Another idea - maybe you can try to do something with scroll snapping (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap), but I am not sure